# Format ArcMap Date format

Tags: arcpy, date

I am really new to Python and I am trying to create a tool using arcpy where I am using the calender as the data type for one of the parameters in the tool. The date format ArcMap is giving me is something like: 9/14/2017. Instead I would like to have a leading zero in front of the date like: 09/14/2017.

How can I keep the date format consistent with a leading zero in front of the date in Python?

Comment: Look at `datetime.strftime ()`

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy+date?sort=votes&pageSize=50